# Trouble with url-pattern in web.xml

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

My filter mapping in `web.xml` is as follows:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>LoginCheckFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.tutorial.filter.LoginCheckFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginCheckFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

When I run my app and hit `http://localhost:8080/admin` my filter is not getting executed. I'm not able to understand why.

Is there any problem with the pattern. Also If I remove `'*'` from the pattern then the filter is getting executed on hitting above url.

Need help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The specifications (paragraph 12.2) says the following:

> In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is
>   used to define mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and
>     ending with a ‘/*’ suffix is used for path mapping.
> - A string
>     beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - The
>     empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the
>     application's context root, i.e., requests of the form
>     `http://host:port/<contextroot>/`. In this case the path info is ’/’ and
>     the servlet path and context path is empty string (““).
> - A string
>     containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of
>     the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI
>     minus the context path and the path info is null.
> - All other strings
>     are used for exact matches only.

So the `*` is taken literally, unless the pattern ends with `/*` or starts with `*.`

Comment: For future reference, this seems to be servlet spec `3.0`. E.g., `The empty string ("")` does not seem valid for version `2.5`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `/admin/*` instead of `/admin*`.

Servlet container will not recognize `/admin*` as correct URL pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

```
<url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
```